# Using multiple values in a using statement in C#?

Tags: c#, using-statement

In Python you can do something like:

```
with open('filename') as f, something_else(f) as thing:
    do_thing(thing)
```

and it will do the `open` bit, then the `something_else` bit. When the block exits it will "dispose" it in reverse order.

Right now I've got some C# code like this:

```
using (var cmd = new DB2Command(...)){
    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
        // Magic super-duper-top-secret-code-here
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can combine `cmd` and `rdr` into one `using` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only do this if the two objects share the same type, and they aren't here.

Note that there's no need for you to use braces on the outer `using`, and the code looks cleaner without it:

```
using (var cmd = new DB2Command(...))
using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    // Magic super-duper-top-secret-code-here
}
```

If the objects are both of the same type you can do this:

```
using(FileStream stream1 = File.Open("", FileMode.Open)
    , stream2 = File.Open("", FileMode.Open))
{
}
```

Comment: @Steven It's a widely used pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
using (var cmd = new DB2Command(...))
using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    // Magic super-duper-top-secret-code-here
}
```

That's the best it will get.

Answer (score 0):

So i'll try something not using using...

```
    public void processDisposables<T1, T2>(T1 type1, T2 type2, Action<T1, T2> action)
        where T1: IDisposable
        where T2: IDisposable {

            try {
                action(type1, type2);
            } finally {
                type1.Dispose();
                type2.Dispose();
            }
    }
```

and it's usage:

```
    processDisposables(new MemoryStream(), new StringReader("Frank Borland is 112"), (m, s) => {
        m.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        // other stuff with IDisposables
    });
```